# c++: Behaviour of pointer data member in class inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

```
class Base {

    protected:
            string m_strName;
            char* pchChar;
    public:
            Base()
            {
                    m_strName = "Base";
                    pchChar   = NULL;
            };

           void display()
            {
                    printf(" display name : %s %c\n",m_strName.c_str(),pchChar);
             };
  };

 class Derived : protected Base {
       public:
               Derived()
               {
                       init();
               };

            void init()
            {
                    m_strName = "Derived";
                    pchChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(pchChar,"A");
                    printf(" char %c\n",*pchChar);
                    display();
            };
};

int main()
{
        Derived* pDerived = new Derived();
        return 0;
}
```

The observed output is

```
    char A
    display name : Derived P
```

whereas i expected pchChar should have value "A" on both occasions.
am i missing any piece of information??
pls suggest.

Comment: Also, you only allocated one byte of storage for pchChar, but strcpy() is going to write two bytes there (the character 'A' and the null terminator).

Comment: Please, edit the question to correct the indentation. While this piece of code is small, once things get bigger, having a consistent form of indentation will help *you* (and others) read the source code. Also consider removing whitespace, there is only a limited size of code that can fit in the code window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `*`:

```
printf(" display name : %s %c\n",m_strName.c_str(), *pchChar);
```

It should be `*pchChar`, not `pchChar`. Because you're printing it as `%c`.

Or you can use `%s` as format string,  and your printf would work, if the c-string is null-terminated string. Currently its not null-terminated. You should be doing this:

```
pchChar = (char*)malloc( 2 * sizeof(char)); //2 chars, one for `\0`
strcpy(pchChar,"A");
```

Or even better use `new`, and `std::cout`.

Also, don't forget to call `free` with `malloc` to deallocate the memory once you're done with it. And if you use `new`, use `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf(" display name : %s %c\n",m_strName.c_str(),pchChar);
```

should be:

```
printf(" display name : %s %c\n",m_strName.c_str(),*pchChar);
```

The first will coerce the *pointer* into a character and will therefore depend entirely upon *where* that character is located in your address space.

The second will correctly *dereference* the pointer to get at the character, exactly as you have done so in the `init` code of your derived class.

And this little snippet:

```
pchChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

does *not* allocate enough space for the `"A"` string, you need two characters for that:

```
pchChar = (char*)malloc(2); // sizeof(char) is ALWAYS 1 !!!
```

Or better yet, don't use `malloc` at all. Although C++ provides those facilities for C compatibility, you're probably better off using `new` and `delete`.